# Assembly code from Ocaml

Tags: assembly, ocaml, disassembly

I have simple ocaml file test.ml

```
1 + 2;;
```

I compiled it. can i see assembly output of this code? Maybe ocaml packet has any tools for this?

Thank you.

Comment: You probably can, but it will probably contain a lot of boilerplate meaning nothing to you and if the compiler even tried to optimize, there will be no code at all for `1 + 2;;` as it's a no-op.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can: see below. Everything that remains from your code is `movl $7, %eax` (7 is OCaml's representation for 3, which is the result of 1+2).

```
$ cat > t.ml
1 + 2 ;;
$ ocamlopt -S t.ml
$ cat t.s 
    .data
    .globl  _camlT__data_begin
_camlT__data_begin:
    .text
    .globl  _camlT__code_begin
_camlT__code_begin:
    nop
    .data
    .long   0
    .globl  _camlT
_camlT:
    .text
    .align  4
    .globl  _camlT__entry
_camlT__entry:
    subl    $12, %esp
L100:
    movl    $7, %eax
    movl    $1, %eax
    addl    $12, %esp
    ret
    .data
    .text
    nop
    .globl  _camlT__code_end
_camlT__code_end:
    .data
    .globl  _camlT__data_end
_camlT__data_end:
    .long   0
    .globl  _camlT__frametable
_camlT__frametable:
    .long   0
    .section __IMPORT,__pointers,non_lazy_symbol_pointers
    .section __IMPORT,__jump_table,symbol_stubs,self_modifying_code+pure_instructions,5
```